# Python - Beautiful Soup: Extract "strings" from tag in right order

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm searching for a beautiful soup command combination to extract "strings" from a-tag string in the right order.

Source 1:
`<a href="target" title="title">a-string <img alt="img-alt"> <span>span-string</span></a>`

Target 1:
"a-string img-alt span-string"

Source 2:
`<a href="target" title="title"><span>span</span> string <img alt="alt"></a>`

Target 2:
"span-string a-string img-alt"

It's easy to get the child elements via "find_all()" and the text via "get_text()".

How to get the right order of the different "strings"? Or to sequentially parse all information in the a-string?

Comment: What are these "strings" you are looking for? Why not `target-title-a-string -img-al span-string` and `target-title-span string-alt`?

Comment: Sometimes we "guard" values by replacing single characters through images of this letter, e.g. "<a href="target" title="title">hell<img alt="o"><span>dude</span></a>"

Answer (score 0):

For 1:

```
import bs4
a = bs4.BeautifulSoup("""<a href="target" title="title">a-string <img alt="img-alt"> <span>span-string</span></a>""")
print(" ".join((a.find(text=True),a.find("img").attrs["alt"],a.find("span").text)))
```

For 2:

```
import bs4
a = bs4.BeautifulSoup("""<a href="target" title="title">a-string <img alt="img-alt"> <span>span-string</span></a>""")
print(" ".join((a.find("span").text, a.find(text=True), a.find("img").attrs["alt"])))
```

I don't think that there's a generic way to extract what you want, as you are mixing text content and attributes.

```
a.find(text=True) ## Get first element text
a.findAll(text=True) ## Get a list of text elements from string
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is the answer you are looking for...the `contents` method returns a list

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

s="""<a href="target" title="title">a-string <img alt="img-alt"> <span>span-string</span></a>"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(s)
z=soup.find("a")
print z.contents
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [lxml](http://lxml.de/),

```
import lxml.html as LH
content = '''
<a href="target" title="title">a-string <img alt="img-alt"> <span>span-string</span></a>
<a href="target" title="title"><span>span</span> string <img alt="alt"></a>
'''

root = LH.fromstring(content)
for atag in root.xpath('//a'):
    print(' '.join(atag.xpath('''
        descendant-or-self::text()
        |
        descendant-or-self::*/@alt
        ''')))
```

yields

```
a-string  img-alt span-string
span  string  alt
```